# Check db on another server PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can i do a query on another server and return me the $query?

I have my main database with licenses values (supposing  on `http://www.example.com/`).
Like this:

```
ID | URL                   | Licence

1  | www.client1.com       | A12345

2  | www.client2.com       | B12345
```

Supposing that i am client1.com, i need to check if on my localhost db my license is equal to main database on example.com.

I tried on client like this, return on server on name but i can't compare the result:

```
$fields = array('licence' => 'A12345'); 
$homepage = file_get_contents(REMOTE_HOST . http_build_query($fields));     
if($homepage == 'Games2Trade'){         
    echo 1;     
} else {        
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: If I understand you right you want to do a query to another server, then you have to connect to their database in order to do so, you will need the user and password then you do your query. But in your code it seens that you are trying to read the page from the other server. Which one you want to do?

Comment: I just want to get a $array from example.com with all information, like name and things like that. My problem is how can i get that array from example.com to cliente1.com. I don't want to use mysql remotly, then i'm trying to call a file call.php on example.com that does the query with info by $_GET and do the query and return $rowQuery and on cliente1.com use that $query. I tried to read the the content with file_get_contents but i really need and array with all information from mysql_fetch_array done on example.com

Comment: It seems you need web service. You can use REST or SOAP. I would preffer REST, because it is simple